# Line color for OHLC chart

Tags: core-plot

How can we indicate the increasing Line and decreasing line of OHLC Chart in different color?
FOr candlestick we have increaseFill and decreaseFill Property. But for OHLC? Is there any property? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should submit an enhancement request on the [Core Plot issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

In the meantime, you could create two plots—one for the increasing values and one for the decreasing ones.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I did that as You said.